# Are fielders (non-catchers) allowed to start from foul territory, and where should the catcher be?

Tags: rules, softball

Are fielders (not being the catcher) allowed to start in foul territory? This is actually something that I did. As a left outfielder I played/started on foul territory, because of a very strong and low sun in my eyes elsewhere. It could also be useful for right fielders with very fast pitchers. Or place a fielder at the back-stop for a wild pitch.

Also, is it allowed to have the catcher at the back-stop (fence), or right next to the home dug-out (say, for catching foul balls), or somewhere right of the right foul-line but 60 yards away from home plate, or in the infield six feet away from the plate?

Which rule applies, if any?

Comment: So, these are actually two questions, of which both you seem to know the answer already. Please read more [about] asking questions in the [help]. Welcome to Sports beta !!

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Thanks for the welcome! However, I do not know the answers. I only assume that, if they are covered, they are covered by the same rule. I have my intuition, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

**American Softball Association:**

Ref: http://files.leagueathletics.com/Text/Documents/13338/35721.pdf

The **American Softball Association** does not actively publish their **Official Rules - Umpire Edition**, but I was able to find a 2005 legacy copy at the ref link above.

On Page 84 (PDF page 86):

> Section 5. DEFENSIVE POSITIONING.
>
> > A. The pitcher shall not deliver a pitch unless all defensive players are positioned in fair territory, except the catcher who must be in the catcher’s
> >     box.
> >
> > B. A fielder shall not take a position in the batter’s line of vision or, with
> >     deliberate unsportsmanlike intent, acts in a manner to distract the batter.
> >     A pitch does not have to be released. The offending player shall also be
> >     ejected from the game.

The rules on **Defensive Positioning** are found in each type of pitching rule sections (Fast Pitch, Modified Pitch, Slow Pitch, 16-inch Slow Pitch)

Comment: Makes sense.  The rule presumably exists to prevent players from pretending to be off the field but actually being a live player (to confuse the batter/runners).

Answer (score 1):

**Major League Baseball:**

Ref: http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2014/official_baseball_rules.pdf

- Question 1: On page 32 (PDF page 38):

> 4.03 When the ball is put in play at the start of, or during a game, all fielders other than the catcher shall be on fair territory.
>
> > (a) The catcher shall station himself directly back of the plate. He may
> >     leave his posi- tion at any time to catch a pitch or make a play
> >     except that when the batter is being given an intentional base on
> >     balls, the catcher must stand with both feet within the lines of the
> >     catcher’s box until the ball leaves the pitcher’s hand. PENALTY: Balk.
> >
> > (b) The pitcher, while in the act of delivering the ball to the
> >     batter, shall take his legal position;
> >
> > (c) Except the pitcher and the
> >     catcher, any fielder may station himself anywhere in fair territory.

- Question 2: On page 3 (PDF page 9) the catcher's box is drawn out. 
  On page 13 (PDF page 19) the definition is defined as

> The CATCHER’S BOX is that area within which the catcher shall stand
>   until the pitcher delivers the ball.

Comment: This is a good answer for MLB, but the question was tagged [tag:softball], which would have a separate rulebook.

Comment: @Joe Good Call... I'll see what I can find.  However, the user is no longer a valid account so it is highly likely to get accepted or additional views.